# Rake tasks to work with mercurial and visual sourcesafe

Tags: ruby, mercurial, rake, rubygems, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to use Rake to build a solution on the build machine. The solution consists of multiple projects. Some of them are hosted in Mercurial repository and some of them in Visual SourceSafe. I was trying to find a gem with rake tasks which are able to pull the project files from these repositories, but I wasn't succeed. Can anyone suggest such gem(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I didn't found any of rake libraries that provide tasks for work with VSS, I made "get-from-vss" task by myself. If somebody needs to use it, it could be found in [my fork](https://github.com/ziez/Albacore/blob/master/lib/albacore/vssget.rb) of [Albacore](https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore) library.